# Position: fixed and width 100% in ios

Tags: ios, css, fixed, fixed-width

I have an element that is fixed to the top of the page, and scrolls with you when you scroll horizontally.

But in ios width of menu are not a 100% width of viewport. Width of menu is a 900px.

What's a problem? I can set width with JS, but it not true way. At the android devices it's ok, and work great.

```css
body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu
{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fff;
}

.content800
{
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.content900
{
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='menu'>Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 1 Menu 2</div>
  <div class="content800"></div>
  <div class="content900"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I set width of fixed menu by 100% of device screen?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are causing the page to overflow due to `.content800` and `.content900`, when using responsive design you should avoid setting any 'fixed' widths that exceed the devices resolution in either portrait or landscape. You have the viewport set in the HTML but you don't have any media queries in your CSS.

You really need to make use of the media queries using something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em) {
.content800, .content900 {
    width:100%;
    }   
}
```

You may need to change `63.9375em` to your liking as its all small devices in both landscapes, portraits and also tablets in portrait mode. If that doesn't fix your problem then it'll something else that you have failed to attach, like the rest of your CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set `right: 0;` to `.menu`, to make sure the menu covers the whole screen width.

Comment: Sounds like a band aid rather than addressing the issue. My money is on the fact that the fixed width of 900px will exceed iPhones 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 in portrait mode, which will cause a overflow.